# docker_service - provisioning docker container with ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

I use following module:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_service_module.html?highlight=ansible%20doc

I can create and start docker container using this module. However, is it possible to execute tasks (and preserve changes) on this container?
I mean:
install some yum package
insert some bash script into container.

Could you give me some clues?

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you don't install software on a running container.  If you need a container with some software installed in it, you should build a custom image that has the software you need, and set it up so that it can do everything it needs on its own once you start it up once.  (As an even broader rule, you shouldn't need to `docker exec` into a running container except to debug things; it definitely isn't part of the core "how to do things with containers" workflow.)

I would recommend following a standard Docker tutorial, such as Docker's [official tutorial on building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/).  Once you have a working Docker image workflow, you'd use the Ansible `docker_container` module in place of the `docker run` command.